# Unable to apply custom roles in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to create a custom role for dummy123@gmail.com so that it can only view deploy and delete pods in the namespace 'test' but for any other namespace it cannot delete and deploy anything i have deployed this yaml file and it is working fine for deployment the pod can only be created on 'test' namespace not in 'elk' namespace but when i try to delete the pod it cannot be deleted.

here are my both yaml:

```
====role.yaml=======
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: test
  name: pod-manager
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create", "delete", "list"]



=====rolebind.yaml=======

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-manager-binding
  namespace: test
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: dummy@gmail.com
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: pod-manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

I want to set role so that user can access the pod on a single namespace only.
This is the error which is being showed.

**Error from server (Forbidden): pods "lightweight-pod" is forbidden: User "dummy@gmail.com" cannot delete resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default": RBAC: [clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "pod-manager" not found, clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "restricted-pod-reader" not found, role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "pod-manager" not found]
requires one of ["container.pods.delete"] permission(s).**